# NSFetchedResultsController - crash after removing all rows from section

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm using UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController. All methods of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate are implemented similar to Apple's documentation. But I receive "Invalid update" exception after removing all section's rows from database.

Delegate process this action in following order:

- Firstly executes **controller:didChangeSection:** method and removes section which become empty.
- Then excecutes **controller:didChangeObject:** method, which tries to remove rows from already removed section. It causes the exception.

What am I making wrong and how to process this situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But if you "group" all changes by adding:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

It sould work just fine.